# Beginning SuperCollider

Tags: audio, supercollider

I've just started to learn SuperCollider and I have some questions.  First, beyond http://doc.sccode.org/Tutorials/Getting-Started are there any beginner resources online? Like code patterns examples, worked examples etc.? Second, the code in https://sccode.org/ (the does not seem to be an accompanying discussion forum) generally does not work for me when I paste it into SuperCollider 3.13.0-rc1. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend this book: [https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~ruviaro/texts/A_Gentle_Introduction_To_SuperCollider.pdf](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Eruviaro/texts/A_Gentle_Introduction_To_SuperCollider.pdf) .